# Clearing setTimeout when $http call is in pending

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, settimeout, angular-promise

```
function getDBCounts() {
    $http.get('URL')
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.stats = response.data;
            $scope.getDBCountsTimeOut = setTimeout(getDBCounts, 5000);
         }, function () {
             $scope.getDBCountsTimeOut = setTimeout(getDBCounts, 5000);
         })
}


$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    clearTimeout($scope.getDBCountsTimeOut);
});
```

when ever I am going to different controller I am making sure I am cancelling all timeouts but the issue is when the $http call is in pending and I am moving to different controller at the same time (the timeout is not being created until we get the response) and I am unable to cancel that timeout on controller change since the call is in pending state and I cannot clear a timeout which is not been created.

How do I handle this situation. what is the best solution for this issue.

I have done this but in the error section I am unable to differentiate the network error and cancelled timeout because I need to still call setTimeout if it is network error.

```
$scope.canceler = $q.defer();
function getDBCounts() {
     $http
       .get(apiUri + '/backend/database/stats', {timeout: $scope.canceler.promise})
        .then(function (response){
              $scope.stats = response.data;
              $scope.getDBCountsTimeOut = setTimeout(getDBCounts, 5000);
          }, function (er, second) {
              $scope.getDBCountsTimeOut = setTimeout(getDBCounts, 5000);
          })
 }

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
   clearTimeout($scope.getDBCountsTimeOut);
    $scope.canceler.resolve();
});
```

For both network error and timeout i get this as a response:

```
{config: Object
data: null
headers: (name)
status: 0
statusText: ""}
```

Now how do I resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will get a network error on a timeout/abort.

Comment: Use `$timeout` it has better integration with the $q service , the AngularJS framework, and has a cancel method.

Comment: @if you are using visual studio 2013 or greater, then this will help you - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f90965f-2f5e-47ba-b337-ad55f95c5b61?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of the `$http` API. I would also have expected that you can tell from the response/error, whether the request has timed out.

The only way I see here is that you don't cancel the promise but set a flag in the scope when it has been destroyed. Then you simply don't set the timeouts when the scope has already been destroyed:

```
function getDBCounts() {
    $http.get('URL')
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.stats = response.data;
         })
         .finally(function() {
             if (!$scope.destroyed) {
                 $scope.getDBCountsTimeOut = setTimeout(getDBCounts, 5000);
             }
         })
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    clearTimeout($scope.getDBCountsTimeOut);
    $scope.destroyed = true;
});
```

Your approach is better and would be the "correct" way. However, it seems this is not possible.

PS: If you want to do something regardless of whether a promise has been resolved or rejected, you should use `finally` (see above). Please note that in older browser (and thus older JS/ECMA-Script versions) `finally` is a reserved word. If you want to make sure that older browsers are supported, call it like this:

```
$http.get(...)["finally"](function() {
})
```